# Eclipse Plugin Open Preferences Page From Menu Item

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

I have a

```
public class PrefMenu extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage
```

implementing the init() and createFieldMethods(). And I do see it in Window>Preferences>PREFMENU_NAME after adding the class to the preferencePage extension.

But how do I open the preference page from a menu-item? I created a command and a handler and the execute()-Method (which works with other commands) does...

```
    //other commands
    } else if (commandID.equals(PREFERENCES_COMMAND_ID)){
        final PrefMenu prefMenu = new PrefMenu();
        prefMenu.init(PlatformUI.getWorkbench());
    }
```

Yet nothing happens when I click on the menu-Item. In the debug mode I see it simply executes the init()-Method and returns. But I want it to open up the Preferences-Window and only close it when I click on OK or Cancel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil` to do this:

```java
String id = ... your preference page id

Shell shell = ... parent shell to use ...

PreferencesUtil.createPreferenceDialogOn(shell, id, new String[] {id}, null).open()
```

This will open just your preference page in the preferences dialog. You can adjust the string array to include other pages or specify `null` for the array to show all preference pages.